# Jquery ui animate function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Following an example from a question on So I tried the following code (part of it, not the whole thing):

```
function fadeDivIn(){
    $('#helpdocButton').animate({backgroundColor: "#ed3" }, 4000, function(){fadeDivOut();});
}

function fadeDivOut(div){
    $('#helpdocButton').animate({backgroundColor: "#3de" }, 4000, function(){fadeDivIn();});
}

$(function() {

  $('#helpdocButton').click(function(){
    $('menu').hide('slow');
    $('helpdoc').show('slow')
  });

  $('#helpdocButton').mouseover(function(){
    fadeDivIn();//it should start the .animate
  });
});
```

my includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

my styles:

```
#helpdocButton {
  width: 67px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00ffff;
  moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid #00ffff;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: 0.45;
}

#helpdocButton:hover {
  -webkit-transition-duration: .90s;
  opacity: 2;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50);
}
```

so, why the animate doesn't work? I have tried to have it starting from the document load instead of the mousover, but that did not work either. I have also tried it on numerous other divs inside of my code. The animate doesn't works with anything. Everything else is fully functional but the fadeDivIn function does not work. Am I doing anything wrong here? Is this incompatible with my includes? Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the Javascript console (F12 on most browsers) for errors?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ecdUW/ though, 4 seconds is a long time for a hover animation.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: Such an old version is bound to have major bugs in newer browsers.

Comment: where can i include the latest version? the error was in the jquery ui

Comment: specifically the error was `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (E,F){return new o.fn.init(E,F)} has no method 'isPlainObject' jquery-ui.min.js:5`

Answer (score 0):

like was said in the comments your using a very old version of jquery  and a fairly recent version of jquery ui... i would put my money on some inconsistencies there..

try updating your include lines to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and give that a shot, and if you need more [google hosted includes in the future - here is the link](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

Answer (score 0):

Put your html code then i can help you: i suggest you to open Inspector element or firebug if there are some errors: i see some strange lines you can correct them but it wont solve your annimation issue

```
$('menu').hide('slow');
$('helpdoc').show('slow')
```

what are 'menu' and 'helpdoc', if they are html tag you can put like this (helpdoc html tag exist?) if they are id do $('#menu') & $('#helpdoc'), if they are classes do $('.menu') & $('.helpdoc'). Then try to see if there are others elements in front of your $('#helpdocButton') element & replace mouseover by hover & test.